# Why can't I declare a variable name that consists of all digits?

Tags: perl

Why can't I declare a variable name that consists of all digits, e.g. `my $123;`?

I know that `$1` is a special variable related to regexes. But `$a` is also a special variable (related to `sort`), and I can declare it in my code like this:

```
my $a;
```

Why can I do that but not

```
my $1;
```

or

```
my $123;
```

Comment: Use ${`n`} where n > 9.

Comment: @sln that will produce a *Modification of a read-only value attempted* in recent Perls (and possibly older ones as well).

Comment: `$a` and `$b` aren't reserved for `sort`. They're exempt from warnings under `use strict 'vars'` because they're used for sorting. You can use them elsewhere, although it's generally considered to be bad style.

Comment: You're kind of asking two separate questions. 1) Why can't I do `my $123;`? 2) Why *can* I do `my $a;`? I've edited your question to make this more apparent. If I misinterpreted your question, feel free to roll back.

Comment: Golfing or just an unmitigated hatred for the guy who has to maintain your code?

Comment: @tjd http://xkcd.com/1421/

Comment: Thank you @ThisSuitIsBlackNot. Edited question is suitable for me.

Comment: @simbabque, I do like that one.

Comment: I just meant `m//${1}1/` should disambiguate capture group 1 from group 11, where the replacement is interpolated. I can't remember if this is excluded from strict refs warnings.

Answer (score 6):

This is documented in the perldoc called [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

> Variable names in Perl can have several formats. Usually, they must begin with a letter or underscore, in which case they can be arbitrarily long (up to an internal limit of 251 characters) and may contain letters, digits, underscores, or the special sequence :: or '. [...]
>
> Perl variable names may also be a sequence of digits or a single punctuation or control character. These names are all reserved for special uses by Perl; for example, the all-digits names are used to hold data captured by backreferences after a regular expression match. [...]

Taking this into account, these names are valid:

```
$a
$foo
$_
$_123
$_foo_bar_baz_
$_____
```

However, that doesn't mean it makes sense having them.

It's always a good idea to name a variable after what it contains. It is very hard to guess what a variable called `$99` might contain. Maybe it's the 99th of something, in which case it should be an array index. Or it could be 99, in which case you could use a constant (`99`).

Comment: +1 generally but particularly for the note about sensible variable names and use of arrays.

Comment: Arrays like `@2` and hashes like `%57132`, however, are read-write. They are always global (you can use `@4` and even `local @4` but it's an error to say `my @4`) and always in the `main` namespace.
As everyone else has said, don't use these in any code unless your heart is black.